# Proving that a double integral converges

Tags: integration, trigonometry, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals, absolute-value

> **Question**:
>
> How do I show that the following integral converges:
>
> $$\mathcal{I}_k:=\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty\left|\cos\left(s\right)\cdot u^{\frac{1}{2k}-1}\cdot\exp\left(-su\right)\right|\space\text{d}s\space\text{d}u\tag1$$
>
> Where $k$ is a positive integer.

---

**My work**:

I started with:

$$\mathcal{I}_k=\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty\left|\cos\left(s\right)\right|\cdot\left|u^{\frac{1}{2k}-1}\right|\cdot\left|\exp\left(-su\right)\right|\space\text{d}s\space\text{d}u=$$
$$\int_0^\infty u^{\frac{1}{2k}-1}\cdot\left\{\int_0^\infty\left|\cos\left(s\right)\right|\cdot\exp\left(-su\right)\space\text{d}s\right\}\space\text{d}u\tag2$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
&\int_0^\infty\left|\cos s\right| e^{-su}\,ds=\\
&\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(
\int_{2k\pi-\pi/2}^{2k\pi+\pi/2}\cos s\,e^{-su}\,ds-
\int_{2k\pi+\pi/2}^{2k\pi+3\pi/2}\cos s\,e^{-su}\,ds
\right)-\int_{-\pi/2}^{0}\cos s\,e^{-su}\,ds=\\
&\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(
{1+e^{\pi u}\over1+u^2}e^{-\pi u/2-2k\pi u}+
{1+e^{\pi u}\over1+u^2}e^{-3\pi u/2-2k\pi u}
\right)-{e^{\pi u/2}-u\over1+u^2}=\\
&{e^{-\pi u/2}+e^{\pi u/2}\over1+u^2}(1+e^{-\pi u})
\sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{-2k\pi u}-{e^{\pi u/2}-u\over1+u^2}=\\
&{e^{-\pi u/2}+e^{\pi u/2}\over1+u^2}(1+e^{-\pi u})
{1\over 1-e^{-2\pi u}}-{e^{\pi u/2}-u\over1+u^2}=\\
&{e^{\pi u/2}\over1+u^2}
{1+e^{-\pi u}\over 1-e^{-\pi u}}-{e^{\pi u/2}-u\over1+u^2}=\\
&{e^{\pi u/2}\over1+u^2}
{2e^{-\pi u}\over 1-e^{-\pi u}}+{u\over1+u^2}.\\
\end{align}
$$
From here, it should not be difficult to take on. But with the presence of a term $1-e^{-\pi u}$ in the denominator I don't see how the integral could converge.